# How to assign the first line from a file that resides in multiple directories to a variable per file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

**Dataset**

```bash
C:\temp\powershelltest\
                      \dir.1\test.txt
                      \dir.2\test.txt
                      \dir.3\test.txt
                      \test.ps1
```

*dir.[0-9]\test.txt*

```bash
file dir[0-9]
helloworld
```

---

**Attempt**

*test.ps1*

```bash
$content = Get-Content "C:\temp\powershelltest\dir.[0-9]\test.txt"

Write-Host $content[0]
```

**Result**

*Current outcome*

```bash
PS C:\Windows\system32> . "C:\temp\powershelltest\test.ps1"
file dir1
```

*Expected outcome*

```bash
PS C:\Windows\system32> . "C:\temp\powershelltest\test.ps1"
file dir1
file dir2
file dir3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Content` doesn't do filtering with Regex but with [approved wildcards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I would approach this with `Get-ChildItem` and your wilcards. *Note* Also you need to specify `Recurse` to get results from subfolders

```bash
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\powershelltest\dir.[0-9]" -Recurse -Filter "test.txt" | 
    ForEach-Object{ Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1}
```

That should pull the first line from every "test.txt" document that has "dir." followed by a single digit for a parent directory.

which results in:

```bash
PS C:\Windows\system32> . "C:\temp\powershelltest\test.ps1"
file dir1
file dir2
file dir3
```

Comment: @utrecht I approved the edit for now. My solution does have to loops already. I will test with your data set and see what happens. Also fixed the syntax error with the missing `}` thats what i get for writing code outside ISE.

Comment: @utrecht so the first line in text.txt contains "file dir#" where # is the directory number?

Comment: @utrecht Tested this with your data sample. Incorporated your gci path as it was cleaner then using a where clause. No need to assign to a variable as it gets output straight to the console

Comment: Minor issue: `Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\powershell\dir.[0-9]"` should be `Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\powershelltest\dir.[0-9]" `

Comment: @utrecht i did my test with just "c:\temp\powershell". didnt even notice. I updated it. THanks